# Convert months to German acronym

Tags: python, date, date-formatting

I am looking for a solution to convert English names for "Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May" to "Jan, Feb, Mär, Apr, Mai". I already tried to include "locale". I also have a column with a Timestamp-Series, may this helps

```
import locale
import pandas as pd

locale.getlocale()
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'deu_deu')

d = {'en_month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
     'Datetimeindex':['2021-01-31', '2021-02-28', '2021-03-31', '2021-04-30','2021-05-31' ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Datetimeindex'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Datetimeindex'],  format= '%Y/%m/%d')

#df['german'] = df['Datetimeindex'].strftime('%B') #< not the solution
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may somebody has a more elegant solution.

```
import locale
import pandas as pd
locale.getlocale()
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE')

d = {'en_month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
     'Datetimeindex':['2021-01-31', '2021-02-28', '2021-03-31', '2021-04-30','2021-05-31' ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Datetimeindex'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Datetimeindex'],  format= '%Y/%m/%d')

df['new'] = df['Datetimeindex'].dt.strftime('%B')
df['new'] = df['new'].str[:3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE')` instead of `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'deu_deu')` (deu is not a valid locale name)

Comment: 'deu_deu" also works (i am using windows). if i usin my code i get the full name of the month. but i am looking for the acronym. i

Comment: a solution would be:
```
df['new'] = df['Datetimeindex'].dt.strftime('%B')
df['new'] = df['new'].str[:3]
```
may the is a more elegant solution